# cakephp pagination with AND OR condition inside loop

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am working with cakephp pagination i am using 2 group of check box for filter **materialtype** and **occasion** so i wrote following code

```
public function index($category) {

if(!empty($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['materialtype']))
{
foreach ($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['materialtype'] as $v){
$conditions1[] ="(Product.materialtype LIKE '%$v%')";
}
$conditions[] = implode(' OR ', $conditions1);
}

if(!empty($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['occasion']))
{
foreach ($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['occasion'] as $v){
$conditions2[] ="`Product`.`occasion` LIKE '%$v%'";
}
$conditions[] = implode(' OR ', $conditions2);
}

}
```

My following code is generating this sql query

```
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`category`, `Product`.`name`, FROM mydb`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Necklace' AND (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%Yellow Gold%') OR (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%White Gold%') AND (`Product`.`occasion` LIKE '%Traditional%') OR (`Product`.`occasion` LIKE '%Modern%')
```

But I am looking for this output.

```
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`category`, `Product`.`name`, FROM mydb`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`category` = 'Necklace' AND ((`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%Yellow Gold%') OR (`Product`.`materialtype` LIKE '%White Gold%')) AND ((`Product`.`occasion` LIKE '%Traditional%') OR (`Product`.`occasion` LIKE '%Modern%'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove inner bracket from the inner statement inside the foreach. and add it at with outside like below.

```
if(!empty($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['materialtype']))
{
       foreach ($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['materialtype'] as $v){
            $conditions1[] = "Product.materialtype LIKE '%$v%'";
       }
       $str_cond = implode(' OR ', $conditions1);
       $conditions[] = '(' . $str_cond . ')';
}

if(!empty($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['occasion']))
{
    foreach ($this->params['url']['data']['filter']['occasion'] as $v){
        $conditions2[] = "Product.occasion LIKE '%$v%'";
    }
    $str_cond = implode(' OR ', $conditions2);
    $conditions[] = '(' . $str_cond . ')';
}
```

Comment: your code helped me but it is exactly not working i just updated my quesion can you check back.